# Docker Golang exec being built but exec not copied to run in scratch

Tags: docker

I am attempting to build a docker container for a Golang web server. The code gets copied and compiled successfully, but the copy to my scratch image doesn't seem to be working. Partial snippet from docker build and run is:

```
Successfully built 04e756126739
Successfully tagged robtcallahan/vue-register:latest
[18:26:17] robs-mac [~/ws/go/src/vue-register] docker*> docker run -p 9000:9000 robtcallahan/vue-register
exec /bin/vue-register: no such file or directory
```

My Dockerfile is as follows:

```
FROM golang:1.21

WORKDIR /src
COPY go.mod .
COPY go.sum .
RUN go mod download

COPY ./ ./
RUN go build -o /bin/vue-register
RUN ls -l /bin/vue-register

FROM scratch
COPY --from=0 /bin/vue-register /bin/vue-register

EXPOSE 9000
CMD ["/bin/vue-register", "server"]
```

Here's the build and run output:

```
[18:18:59] robs-mac [~/ws/go/src/vue-register] docker*> docker build --tag robtcallahan/vue-register .

Sending build context to Docker daemon   58.3MB
Step 1/15 : FROM golang:1.21
 ---> 57ca605b665e
Step 2/15 : ENV BIN_DIR=/bin
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 903f2932af2f
Step 3/15 : ENV APP_NAME=vue-register
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 2557654f0d13
Step 4/15 : ENV APP_OPTIONS=serve
 ---> Using cache
 ---> a2c041eaf09f
Step 5/15 : WORKDIR /src
 ---> Using cache
 ---> c4fa69385912
Step 6/15 : COPY go.mod .
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 9553f04ef090
Step 7/15 : COPY go.sum .
 ---> Using cache
 ---> dbf95cefbb59
Step 8/15 : RUN go mod download
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 7410a7be97d5
Step 9/15 : COPY ./ ./
 ---> 2989a0f5fa70
Step 10/15 : RUN go build -o /bin/vue-register
 ---> Running in 00cbd8c790d4
Removing intermediate container 00cbd8c790d4
 ---> 4b9953ae6836
Step 11/15 : RUN ls -l /bin/vue-register
 ---> Running in d15b5d06e626
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 29480428 Sep 20 22:26 /bin/vue-register
Removing intermediate container d15b5d06e626
 ---> 1d81a4781351
Step 12/15 : FROM scratch
 ---> 
Step 13/15 : COPY --from=0 /bin/vue-register /bin/vue-register
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 5f79a1d62035
Step 14/15 : EXPOSE 9000
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 8782444f0a3e
Step 15/15 : CMD ["/bin/vue-register", "server"]
 ---> Running in e7166f320713
Removing intermediate container e7166f320713
 ---> 04e756126739
Successfully built 04e756126739
Successfully tagged robtcallahan/vue-register:latest

[18:26:17] robs-mac [~/ws/go/src/vue-register] docker*> docker run -p 9000:9000 robtcallahan/vue-register
exec /bin/vue-register: no such file or directory
```

Note the output of the `RUN ls -l /bin/vue-register` from Dockerfile shows the compiled exec, but `Docker run` fails. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to have `go build` build a static binary.  The linked question includes a set of `go build` options that will work.